# ListView in the Activity and getting data from server in listview and from adapter refresh the listview by calling same url

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a listview in Activity and getting data from server to generate the listview and now from adapter i have to call the same url to refresh the listview. No data are storing in device. But unable to do it from adapter.how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

What's your problem ? Can you tell it more in detail? If you declare the adapter as the inner class of the activity, simply add a method in the activity and call it. Otherwise add a context or activity parameter to the constructor of the adapter and use it. Use handler or AsyncTask or other way to load the data,   after getting data from server ,      set data to the adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged to refresh data.Hope this help.:)